# How to render HTML tages came from the database?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, components

I am bulding a chat app.  some of the data came from the database, where it contains some HTML tages need to be rendered before send it to the UI.
The following is the component where i wan tto render the HTML tages

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Bubble({ inhalt }) {
  const { text, sender } = inhalt;
  const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState(sender === 'bot' ? '' : text);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0); // We keep a state for every index in the text string

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sender === 'bot') {
      // Check every 100ms if the current index is lesser than the length of the text
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (index < text.length) {
          // If lesser, we increment index by 1 and add the next character from text into the displayText
          setDisplayText(prevText => prevText + text[index]);
          setIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1);
        } else {
          clearInterval(interval); // Else, we clear the Interval
        }
      }, 30);

      // We clear the interval when the component unmounts
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [text, sender, index]);  // effect depends on text, sender, and index

  return (
    <div className={sender === 'user' ? "skillynx-io-bubble user-bubble" : "skillynx-io-bubble bot-bubble"}>
      {displayText}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Bubble;
```

For example if I have the following tage:

```
<sort-paragraph>
            <p class="draggable"  id= "1"><b>First paragraph</b></p>
            <p class="draggable"  id= "2"><b>second pararaph </b></p>
            <p class="draggable"  id= "3" >Third paragraph</p>   
</sort-paragraph>
```

In JS when I get search in th DOM for such tages and it corresponding function like this:

```
   function sortParagraph(element, callback) {

        var checkLine = ce('div', 'diadibi-check-line')
            , container = ce('div', 'draggableContainer')
            , btnCheck = ce('div', 'btn btn-primary', 'Überprüfen')
            , btnRetry = ce('div', 'btn btn-primary', 'Wiederholen')
            , btnShowAnswer = ce('div', 'btn btn-primary', 'Die Antwort anzeigen')
            , dragElements = []
            ;

        btnRetry.style.margin = "1rem";
        btnShowAnswer.style.margin = "1rem";
        const draggables = element.getElementsByClassName('draggable');
        if (draggables) {
            for (let i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++) {
                let draggableElement = draggables[i];

                draggableElement.draggable = true;

                dragElements.push(draggableElement);
                draggableElement.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
                    draggableElement.classList.add('dragging');
                })

                draggableElement.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
                    draggableElement.classList.remove('dragging');

                })


            }
        } else console.log("****Did not find draggable Class ***");


        container.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY);
            const draggable = element.querySelector('.dragging');

            if (draggable) {
                if (afterElement == null) {
                    container.appendChild(draggable);
                }
                else {
                    container.insertBefore(draggable, afterElement);
                }
            }

        });

        //



        btnCheck.addEventListener('click', check);

        btnRetry.addEventListener('click', Retry);
        btnShowAnswer.addEventListener('click', ShowAnswre);


        Retry()
 function Retry() {....}
function check() {...}
function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {...}
```

dangerouslySetInnerHTML, and ReactHtmlParser